# JAX-WS didn't get response on Websphere 8.5

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, websphere

I got a job that I have to generate WS client from WSDL to communicate with server. I use WSImport(JAX-WS) to do the job because it seems less conflicts to different server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:conv="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/soap/conversation/" xmlns:cw="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/wsdl/conversation/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:jms="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/wsdl/jms/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:s0="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.openuri.org/">    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ope="http://www.openuri.org/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.openuri.org/">
            <s:element name="getRSAPublicKey">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="length" type="s:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></s:element>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="getRSAPublicKeyResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="getRSAPublicKeyResult" type="ope:RSAPublicKeyResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:complexType name="RSAPublicKeyResponse">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element name="module" type="s:string"
                        minOccurs="0" />
                    <s:element name="exponent" type="s:string"
                        minOccurs="0" />
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="getRSAPublicKeySoapIn">
        <wsdl:part element="s0:getRSAPublicKey" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getRSAPublicKeySoapOut">
        <wsdl:part element="s0:getRSAPublicKeyResponse" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="TestClientSoapPortType">
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
        <wsdl:operation name="getRSAPublicKey">
            <wsdl:documentation>Web service to get RSA public key</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="s0:getRSAPublicKeySoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="s0:getRSAPublicKeySoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="TestClientSoapBinding"
        type="s0:TestClientSoapPortType">

        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="getRSAPublicKey">

            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://www.openuri.org/getRSAPublicKey" />
            <wsdl:input>

                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>

                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>


    <wsdl:service name="TestClient">
    <wsdl:port binding="s0:TestClientSoapBinding" name="TestClientSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://localhost:8888/TestClientWS/TestClient.jws"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Then I'm using the following code to post and get my reply

```
        TestClient tClient = new TestClient(new URL("http://localhost/testws.wsdl"));
        TestClientSoapPortType tcSPT = tClient.getTestClientSoap();
        GetRSAPublicKey getRSAPublicKey = new GetRSAPublicKey();
        getRSAPublicKey.setLength("1024");
        GetRSAPublicKeyResponse resp = tcSPT.getRSAPublicKey(getRSAPublicKey);

        out.println("Module: " + resp.getGetRSAPublicKeyResult().getModule());
        out.println("Exponent: " + resp.getGetRSAPublicKeyResult().getExponent());
```

After exported them as a WAR, this code works good on Tomcat server and prints what I want. But when I put it onto Websphere, it somehow broken and prints `Module:  null` and `Exponent: null` to me? HOW??

My goal is to make it work on WAS, but this issue strikes me hard with no exception messages(Even I used `Exception` to try to catch). Does anyone know how to fix this issue on WAS?

Comment: you have to look in the logs on there server side and see whats going on. You probably have some errors in the service thats why you have null returned.

Comment: there side? you mean the server that my client connect to? they said they do gave the response and I could get em while I'm running this client on tomcat.

Comment: So maybe compare xml soap messages that are sent/receive by Tomacat and WAS and see if there are any differences.

Comment: hmm, not sure how I can do that to intercept the message before I send, or take the Raw message that I received before it is processed by Jax-WS. Is there any java programming way to do this?

Comment: For example wireshark, you could also enable tracing on the WebSphere side Check [Tracing web services](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/twbs_tracewbscomp.html). Try setting `com.ibm.ws.webservices.trace.MessageTrace=finest:com.ibm.ws.webservices.
engine.Message=finest`